# Numba Compatable Memoization

Tags: python, numba, memoization

I have just discovered numba, and learnt that optimal performance requires adding `@njit` to most functions, such that numba rarely exits LLVM mode.

I still have a few expensive/lookup functions that could benefit from memoization, but so far none of my attempts have found a workable solution that compiles without error.

- Using common decorator functions, before `@njit` results in a numba not being able to do type inference.
- Using decorators after `@njit` fails to compile the decorator
- Numba doesn't like the use of `global` variables, even when using `numba.typed.Dict`
- Numba doesn't like using closures to store mutable state
- Removing `@njit` also causes type errors when called from other `@njit` functions

What is the correct way to add memoization to functions when working inside numba?

```
import functools
import time

import fastcache
import numba
import numpy as np
import toolz
from numba import njit

from functools import lru_cache
from fastcache import clru_cache
from toolz import memoize



# @fastcache.clru_cache(None)  # BUG: Untyped global name 'expensive': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'fastcache.clru_cache'>
# @functools.lru_cache(None)   # BUG: Untyped global name 'expensive': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'functools._lru_cache_wrapper'>
# @toolz.memoize               # BUG: Untyped global name 'expensive': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
@njit
# @fastcache.clru_cache(None)  # BUG: AttributeError: 'fastcache.clru_cache' object has no attribute '__defaults__'
# @functools.lru_cache(None)   # BUG: AttributeError: 'functools._lru_cache_wrapper' object has no attribute '__defaults__'
# @toolz.memoize               # BUG: CALL_FUNCTION_EX with **kwargs not supported
def expensive():
    bitmasks = np.array([ 1 << n for n in range(0, 64) ], dtype=np.uint64)
    return bitmasks



# @fastcache.clru_cache(None)  # BUG: Untyped global name 'expensive_nojit': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'fastcache.clru_cache'>
# @functools.lru_cache(None)   # BUG: Untyped global name 'expensive_nojit': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'fastcache.clru_cache'>
# @toolz.memoize               # BUG: Untyped global name 'expensive_nojit': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>
def expensive_nojit():
    bitmasks = np.array([ 1 << n for n in range(0, 64) ], dtype=np.uint64)
    return bitmasks


# BUG: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
#      Use of unsupported opcode (STORE_GLOBAL) found
_expensive_cache = None
@njit
def expensive_global():
    global _expensive_cache
    if _expensive_cache is None:
        bitmasks = np.array([ 1 << n for n in range(0, 64) ], dtype=np.uint64)
        _expensive_cache = bitmasks
    return _expensive_cache


# BUG: The use of a DictType[unicode_type,array(int64, 1d, A)] type, assigned to variable 'cache' in globals,
#      is not supported as globals are considered compile-time constants and there is no known way to compile
#      a DictType[unicode_type,array(int64, 1d, A)] type as a constant.
cache = numba.typed.Dict.empty(
    key_type   = numba.types.string,
    value_type = numba.uint64[:]
)
@njit
def expensive_cache():
    global cache
    if "expensive" not in cache:
        bitmasks = np.array([ 1 << n for n in range(0, 64) ], dtype=np.uint64)
        cache["expensive"] = bitmasks
    return cache["expensive"]


# BUG: Cannot capture the non-constant value associated with variable 'cache' in a function that will escape.
@njit()
def _expensive_wrapped():
    cache = []
    def wrapper(bitmasks):
        if len(cache) is None:
            bitmasks = np.array([ 1 << n for n in range(0, 64) ], dtype=np.uint64)
            cache.append(bitmasks)
        return cache[0]
    return wrapper
expensive_wrapped = _expensive_wrapped()

@njit
def loop(count):
    for n in range(count):
        expensive()
        # expensive_nojit()
        # expensive_cache()
        # expensive_global)
        # expensive_wrapped()

def main():
    time_start = time.perf_counter()

    count = 10000
    loop(count)

    time_taken = time.perf_counter() - time_start
    print(f'{count} loops in {time_taken:.4f}s')


loop(1)  # precache numba
main()

# Pure Python: 10000 loops in 0.2895s
# Numba @njit: 10000 loops in 0.0026s
```

Comment: Is this your real world example? Calculating expensive function with some optimizations when needed is actually faster than a memory lookup (getting rid of the list comprehension and passing a preallocated block of memory into the function). Working with real globals is complicated in Numba and needs workarounds. You can pass for example a memory adress (as an int64) into a compiled function and work with it. (low level callable needed which casts the int64 memory adress to a pointer). eg. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61550054/4045774

Comment: Thank you for the link and the idea of using pointers. My realworld code is a little more complex (Kaggle Connect 4 Competition), so I tried to simplify numba down to a minimalist POC testcase for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You already mentioned that your real code is more complex, but looking at your minimal example, I would recommend the following pattern:

```py
@njit
def loop(count):
    expensive_result = expensive()
    for i in range(count):
        do_something(count, expensive_result)
```

Instead of using a cache, you could pre-compute it outside of the loop and provide the result to the loop body. Instead of using globals, I would recommend you to pass every argument explicitly (always, but especially when using the numba jit).